# Ajax #anchors processing with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, anchor, fragment-identifier

I am looking to standardize the processing of ajax #anchors at the server side, using MVC.

Before a controller action is invoked I want to convert every request with ajax anchors into a request without ajax anchors, so that the controller code does not know there were anchors in the request:

For example:

1) `/user/profile#user/photos` should be treated as `/user/photos`

2) `/main/index#user/profile/33` should be treated as `/user/profile/33`

What is the best technique in MVC to accomplish that?

Comment: Are you sure this even happens?  http://www.mikeduncan.com/named-anchors-are-not-sent/

Comment: emmm... just realized this myself when started writing the code. Neeed to have some javascript preprocessing, to send the anchor info to the server manually.

Answer (score 1):

Anchors are not pushed to the server with the url. One option would be to put the value  `/main/index#user/profile/33` inside a hidden field and get the contents of this from your controller.

However I am not sure how you are using the anchors within the markup page so this may not help!